# Numerical range of a matrix A and UAU*

Tags: matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with containing $0$ in its numerical range. Is it true that $0$ is also contained in the numerical range of $UAU^*$, for some unitary matrix $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a unit vector $u$ with $ \langle Au, u \rangle=0$.  Since $U^{*}$ is a bijection there exits a $v$ with $U^{*}v=u$. $v$ is a unit vector because $U^{*}=U^{-1}$ is an isometry.  Now $ \langle (UAU^{*})v, v \rangle=\langle AU^{*}v, U^{*}v \rangle=\langle Au, u \rangle =0$.